# Angular 4 with Auth0-js error on callback

Tags: angular, single-page-application, auth0

I am still learning about these technologies but nowhere in their documentation and forums I found something related to this strange error. I am using Angular 4 and I want to use Auth0 as my authentication and authorization service. So far I got this.

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: '5Rbzn2n568eZFWgAeZCB5zwox7ZI6Jgm',
    domain: 'credishop.auth0.com',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: 'https://credishop.auth0.com/userinfo',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:5000',      
    scope: 'openid'
  });

  constructor(public router: Router) {}

  public login(): void {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }

  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.setSession(authResult);
        this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:5000/#/app/dashboard']);
      } else if (err) {
        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

  private setSession(authResult): void {
    // Set the time that the access token will expire at
    const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
  }

  public logout(): void {
    // Remove tokens and expiry time from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
    // Go back to the home route
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    // Check whether the current time is past the
    // access token's expiry time
    const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
    return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }

}
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { AuthService } from './../services/auth.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.template.html'
})
export class Dashboard {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }

}
```

The module is way too big to post it here to not create a useless cumbersome post, but it does have the service registered as a provider.

So far I got to this point, I have the login and logout button, and it shows the login button as expected, **AFTER** I click the login button it redirects me to Auth0 hosted login page, I login and in the logs inside Auth0 control panel I see that I logged in succesfully. **BUT**, when it redirects me to my website, it should redirect me to my callback page which is **http://localhost:5000** instead it throws me a 404 page doesnt exist as it tries to go to **http://localhost:5000/#/access_token** that is not set up anywhere in my code.

I have been trying to debug this for 2 days now to no avail, I was wondering if anyone here has any idea on what is happening and where should I start looking to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: stop using {useHash:true} as Angular Guide also suggests this. This solved my issue.